why Vercel deploy serverless function has crashed?
I deployed a node backend app to Vercel and it built successfully. However, when I go to the URL, it just says "500 - Internal Server Error." The build logs indicate that the site was deployed successfully and it works.
and this code is working fine with all api endpoints in my local machine
please review my code and suggest me a solution
my index.js
type himport express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import connectDb from "./database/db.js";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import cloudinary from "cloudinary";
import path from "path";

dotenv.config();

cloudinary.v2.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.Cloud_Name,
  api_key: process.env.Cloud_Api,
  api_secret: process.env.Cloud_Secret,
});

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

//using middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// importing routes
import userRoutes from "./routes/userRoutes.js";
import pinRoutes from "./routes/pinRoutes.js";

// using routes
app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/pin", pinRoutes);


app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Express on Vercel"));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
  connectDb();
});
ere

pakage.json file
type he{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "my backend folder",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build":"npm install && cd client && npm install && npm run build",
    "start": "node backend/index.js",
    "dev":"nodemon backend/index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cloudinary": "^2.4.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "datauri": "^4.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.4.5",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
re


The 500 indicates your application has thrown an unhandled error. Can you try adding some error logging and share the output?
